# does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I hit error `does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'List` at the return of this method. May I know what I miss out?

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieDto>>> GetMovies()
{
    var movies = (from m in _context.Movies
                    select new MovieDto()
                    {
                        MovieTitle = m.MovieTitle,
                        ReleaseDate = m.ReleaseDate,
                        MovieStatus = m.MovieStatus,
                        PhotoFile = m.PhotoFile
                    }).ToList();

    return await movies;
}
```

Comment: `ToList` returns a `List<T>` and not a `Task`. You can't `await` a `List<T>`

Comment: Well `ToList()` is not async, it doesn't return a task. Maybe you wanted to use `ToListAsync()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well `ToList()` is not `async`, it doesn't return a `Task`. Maybe you wanted to use `ToListAsync()`

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieDto>>> GetMovies()
{
    var movies = (from m in _context.Movies
                    select new MovieDto()
                    {
                        MovieTitle = m.MovieTitle,
                        ReleaseDate = m.ReleaseDate,
                        MovieStatus = m.MovieStatus,
                        PhotoFile = m.PhotoFile
                    }).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(await movies);
}
```

Comment: It works. In my case it is not only ToListAsync() but also "return Ok(await movies)" statement also played a vital role.

Comment: Replaced so many lines of code from several classes with this short and sweet solution. Well done and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the LINQ query asynchronously to achieve this

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<MovieDto>> GetMovies () {
        var moviesTask =
            Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
                return (from m in _context.Movies 
                        select new MovieDto () {
                          MovieTitle = m.MovieTitle,
                          ReleaseDate = m.ReleaseDate,
                          MovieStatus = m.MovieStatus,
                          PhotoFile = m.PhotoFile
                }).ToList ();
            });
        var movies = await moviesTask;
        return movies;
    }
```

Comment: It would be much better to use true async with `ToListAsync` instead of blocking a different thread with IO.

Answer (score 0):

Or just extend a function called GetAwaiter() as it said, here's the code:

public static class ExtendClass{
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this AsyncOperation asyncOp)
{
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
asyncOp.completed += obj => { tcs.SetResult(null); };
return ((Task)tcs.Task).GetAwaiter();
}
}

Notice that the class must be static. You can just copy and paste this code to a new class.